# Fetch a Rails ActiveRecord 'datetime' attribute as a DateTime object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord, time

I have an attribute in one of my models that contains a Date/Time value, and is declared using `t.datetime :ended_on` in my migrations.

When I fetch this value using `myevent.ended_on`, I get a `Time` object. The problem is that when I try to use this attribute as an axis in a [Flotilla](http://flotilla.rubyforge.org/) chart, it doesn't work properly because Flotilla only recognizes dates as `Date` or `DateTime` objects.

I thought about writing a virtual attribute that will convert the existing Time value to a DateTime, but I'm wary of doing this, since I've heard that Time can't handle dates later than 2040, and I don't wish to risk creating a "2040 bug" to worry about later.

Is there any way I can persuade ActiveRecord to return DateTime objects for this attribute instead of Time objects?

Comment: If you're on a 64bit machine you shouldn't have problems with dates after 2038. At least I can create Time instances with years far beyond 2038.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a method to override the attribute, as follows:

```
class YourModel

  ....

  def ended_on
    self['ended_on'].to_datetime # if you need date object use to_date instead
  end

  ....
end
```

Hopefully that helps

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the job. The code I actually used was `self['ended_on'] && self['ended_on'].to_datetime` so it won't have any trouble with nil values. I'm still a little worried about 2040, but I guess there will be many new versions of Rails to upgrade to before then anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `Time` Object very easy with `Time::to_date` or `Time::to_datetime`. For more information on this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Time/Conversions.html#M001125

so you should change your code like this:

```
myevent.ended_on.to_date
# or
myevent.ended_on.to_datetime
```