# Rails POR object breaks with DateTime input from ActiveRecord-backed model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, activerecord

I have a Ruby class that calculates overtime.  When I give it input as regular DateTime objects, it works fine:

```
d = DateTime.parse('2014-04-01 05:00')
r = DateTime.parse('2014-04-01 19:45')
ov = OvertimeCalculator.new(depart_time: d, return_time: r)
# ov.total_ot_hours = 3.75
```

But when I give it input of DateTime objects from an ActiveRecord-backed class (my model is named `ManDay`), it goes haywire:

```
md = ManDay.new(departed_at: '2014-04-01 05:00', returned_at: '2014-04-01 19:45')
ov = OvertimeCalculator.new(depart_time: md.departed_at, return_time: md.returned_at)
# ov.total_ot_hours = 324000.0
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Here is my plain old ruby object class.

```
class OvertimeCalculator

  attr_accessor :depart_time, :return_time

  def initialize(attrs={})
    @depart_time    = attrs[:depart_time]
    @return_time    = attrs[:return_time]
  end

  def total_ot_hours
    morning_ot_hours + evening_ot_hours
  end

  private

    def morning_ot_hours
      eight_am = @depart_time.change(hour: 8)
      diff = eight_am - @depart_time
      to_hours(diff)
    end

    def evening_ot_hours
      seven_pm = @depart_time.change(hour: 19)
      diff = @return_time - seven_pm
      to_hours(diff)
    end

    def to_hours(diff)
      hours = diff * 24
      hours > 0 ? hours : 0
    end

end
```

Comment: As a note, 8am is **not** the start of the day plus 8 hours. That could be anywhere from 7am to 9am depending on what day you're on. What you want instead is `@depart_time.at_beginning_of_day.change(hour: 8)`. Same goes for your 7pm calculation.

Comment: Thanks, writing it like you say is a lot cleaner. (I changed it to `@depart_time.change(hour: 8)` because `at_beginning_of_day` is no longer necessary with this change, right?). Everything else is still passing, but the one issue mentioned in the question is still there.

Comment: I'd use `change(hour:8, minute: 0, seconds: 0)` to be sure, otherwise it just switches it to 8:17:23am if you started with 5:17:23am.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `to_datetime` on the inputs before doing any calculations solved this problem as such:

```
# app/models/logical/overtime_calculator.rb
def initialize(attrs={})
  @depart_time    = attrs[:depart_time].to_datetime
  @return_time    = attrs[:return_time].to_datetime
end
```

I am not sure why, but I assume it must be a similar issue to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847688/fetch-a-rails-activerecord-datetime-attribute-as-a-datetime-object?rq=1)

Comment: It could be to do with how subtracting DateTime objects doesn't always produce the sorts of values you're expecting. Casting like this is the way to go to be sure.